# Is there a security concern to use remote: true in Rails 5?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Could there be any security concerns when using remote:true for AJAX implementation in Rails applications?

I'm a student learning Ruby on Rails and became curious why some(our teacher) oppose using "remote: true" feature in Rails, mentioning the security reasons.

Comment: Not really. As long as your rails is configured correctly and it's sending the CSRF token with remote form's (ajax) request, there is no such security concern IIRC.

Comment: I don't think there is any security breach to use Ajax, Ajax request is identical to a "normal" browser request but header is slightly different than HTML request

Comment: @kiddorails, thank you!

Comment: @HardikUpadhyay, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To secure your form submission, rails's form helper auto-generates Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF), which is then validated by the server on form submission.

### Regular Ajax

Often times developers add `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` on their controller to make sure ajax request goes through without controller complaining about it, which is not a good practice. One way around this is to pass CSRF token generated by form helper as a part of Ajax data.

### Rails's `remote: true`

This is the challenge solved by `remote: true`. It passes the CSRF token to the server, so it is secure.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer! CSRF it is! :-)